# RuboCop - How to ignore uses of class variables?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have a Ruby class containing a class variable, but RuboCop does not like this since I get the warning: *Using of class variables in Ruby is considered to be a bad code style*. I would like to suppress this warning in my global configuration, which is why I tried the following:

```
Style/ClassVars:
  Enabled: false
```

This did not seem to change anything as I am still seeing the warning. All the other settings in my global configuration are working just fine. What am I missing here?

Edit: This is the kind of scenario I am referring to, where the class variable **users** is marked with a warning.

```
class User
    @@users = []

    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
        @@users.push(self)
    end

    def self.list_users
        @@users.each { |user| puts user }
    end
end

User.new('Alice')
User.new('Bob')

User.list_users
```

Comment: Which version of RuboCop are you using?

Comment: I am running version 0.52.1.

Comment: The message for `Style/ClassVars` looks different (https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/style/class_vars.rb#L33) than the one you mentioned in your question. Can you please Post the exact and full message from Rubocop and the code line Rubocop complains about?

Comment: I have now provided an example of when this warning occurs. RuboCop will highlight all cases of the class variable **users** with the warning: _Using of class variables in Ruby is considered to be a bad code style_.

Comment: Are you sure RuboCop is behind the warning and not some other tool?

Comment: As an aside to the OP, I've yet run into a code scenario in Ruby where I really needed class vars.  Reconsider your usage of them.

Comment: If RuboCop could leave longer messages, she probably would have said, "Use of class variables in Ruby is considered to be a bad code style. Instead, use a [class instance variable](http://thoughts.codegram.com/understanding-class-instance-variables-in-ruby/) or modify your code so that neither a class variable nor a class instance variable is needed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pasted your code in RubyMine and I see the same warning, but this not a RuboCop warning. RubyMine has its own linter.

See Preferences -> Inspections -> Ruby -> Class variable usage

Comment: This solved my issue. I did not even begin to think that the issue had a source external to RuboCop. Thank you for your solution, I would never have found it on my own.